# How to join two DataFrames and update missing values?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark **2.0** and want to update/merge row values in a DataFrame.

I have two DataFrames (old and new ones) which I want to merge in a way that when the old DataFrame has more rows than the new DataFrame, set the old data value 0.

### Case 1 Merge

Old dataframe:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bc|
## +---+----+----+
```

New dataframe:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bb|
## |  3|  cc|  cc|
## +---+----+----+
```

Result:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bb|
## |  3|  cc|  cc|
## +---+----+----+
```

### Case 2 Update

Old dataframe:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bb|
## |  3|  cc|  cc|
## +---+----+----+
```

New dataframe:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bc|
## +---+----+----+
```

Result:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bc|
## |  3|  00|  00|
## +---+----+----+
```

The key is unique in two cases and in the real case the DataFrames can have many columns.

How can I write Spark/Scala code to realize these two cases in one function?

Comment: What would you want to see in each of the cases?

Comment: How Can I write scala&spark  code to Realize these two case in one function ?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to use a `fullOuterJoin` and a `when` condition.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfa = Seq(
  (1, "aa", "ab"),
  (2, "bb", "bb"),
  (3, "cc", "cc")).toDF("key", "val1", "val2")

val dfb = Seq(
  (1, "aa", "ab"),
  (2, "bb", "bb")).toDF("key", "val1", "val2")

val q = dfa
  .join(dfb, Seq("key"), "outer")
  .select($"key",
     when(dfb("val1").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(dfb("val1")).as("val1"), 
     when(dfb("val2").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(dfb("val2")).as("val2"))
  .orderBy("key")

scala> q.show
+---+----+----+
|key|val1|val2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  aa|  ab|
|  2|  bb|  bb|
|  3|   0|   0|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! in the real case , the dataframe have many coloumn , is there have a simple way to realize this ?

Comment: Anyway , I think your answer can solve my problem, I will test it after a while ,thank you very much !

Comment: You can create an expression and explode it.

Comment: I use spark2.0 and cannot found  "when" and "lit" function. @Alberto Bonsanto

Comment: Consider using `join(...).na.fill()` to fill the nulls.

Comment: @WangCheng you need to import them

Answer (score 1):

Just like @summerbulb suggested in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473129/updating-and-merge-row-values-in-a-spark-dataframe#comment74033883_43474433) you should use `na` operator to fill the missing values.

Note that I use `as` operator to have an alias for the columns.

```
val oldDF = Seq(
  (1, "aa", "ab"),
  (2, "bb", "bb"),
  (3, "cc", "cc")).toDF("key", "val1", "val2")
val newDF = Seq(
  (1, "aa", "ab"),
  (2, "bb", "bc")).toDF("key", "val1", "val2")
val q = oldDF.join(newDF.as("new"), Seq("key"), "outer")
  .select("key", "new.*")
  .na.fill("0")  // <-- na.fill("0") because of String type
  .orderBy("key")

scala> q.show
+---+----+----+
|key|val1|val2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  aa|  ab|
|  2|  bb|  bc|
|  3|   0|   0|
+---+----+----+
```

Depending on the type of the column you may want to use `0` as `String` or `Double` type.

Read up on `as` and `na` in [the scaladoc of Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).